# Approval Workflow in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007, workflow

I want to create Approval Workflow in 2007 sharepoint server.
I follow these links but don't find solution:

http://sharepointsolutions.com/sharepoint-help/blog/2010/03/create-a-detailed-custom-task-notification-with-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/

http://www.gandhipritesh.com/2009/07/create-custom-approval-workflow-using.html

would somebody give me the all steps for creating approval workflow?

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? The links you provided are pretty clear and detailed, what is that you are not able to do?

Comment: should I need to create any column for task list as show "Related list item" in first link?

Comment: how the "Complete Task" button come when Item is editing?